# Linear Algebra Coordinate Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Hi I have a few questions for you guys. I know that every change of coordinate matrix is invertible is true. Is the converse of this statement also true?

> > > **Every invertible matrix is a change of coordinate matrix.**

I can't seem to find a counterexample. Also if a polynomial $p(x)$ is an element of $\{P_n\}$ has exactly two terms. Then for any basis $B$ for $P_n$, the coordinate representation $[p]b$ has exactly two non-zero coordinates?

Can you give me a hint on whether or not this is true or false.

Comment: It seems that this should be true.  What is your definition of a change-of-coordinate matrix?

Comment: n vectors (α1, …, αn) with the property that every vector in the space can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the basis vectors

Comment: @user123204: the columns of any invertible matrix form a basis. Do you see how to answer your question?

Comment: for the 2nd or first question?

Answer (score 1):

If this means a "change of basis matrix", then a matrix is invertible if and only if it is a change of basis matrix.  (See e.g. [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25779/91818).)

The second part seems to be untrue (if I understand correctly).  If we have the polynomial $x+1$ (in the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 1$), it has the coordinate representation $(1,1)$ under the basis $\{1,x\}$ and $(0,1)$ under the basis $\{1,x+1\}$.