# Must eigenvector matrix be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

When reading eigenvector of a matrix, there is a formula:

$AP = PD$

where in $P$, each column is A's eigenvector and $D$ is diagonal matrix with diagonal element being A's eigen values.

Now coming the question:

Is matrix P always invertible? because I often see equation $A = PDP^{-1}$ here and there, but don't know how to proof.

Answer (score 2):

**If $A$ is diagonalizable**, then yes. In some (all? most?) texts the very definition of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ being diagonalizable over a field $F$ (let's assume $\mathbb{R}$) is that there exists a *basis* of $\mathbb{R}^n$ made from the eigenvectors of $A$.

The columns of $P$ are exactly these eigenvectors, and them being a basis implies their linear independence. Hence $P$ is an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you appear to be using is the *spectral theorem*.  It works for real symmetric matrices, but not for real asymmetric matrices (nor indeed for matrices that aren't square).  For that you need the *singular value decomposition.*

For all such issues I'd recommend Gilbert Strang's linear algebra book.

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem that states that eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_k$ corresponding to *distinct* eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dotsc, \lambda_k$ are always linearly independent ([reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29371/859382)).

If we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors will form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $k$ = $n$ ([reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2694134/859382)). Therefore, we need the algebraic and geometric multiplicities for each eigenvalue to be equal (which is also the condition for $A$ being diagonalizable). The algebraic multiplicity always sum to $n$, and we need $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors (given by the geometric multiplicity). Also, if $n \neq k$, then $P$ is not square, so it won't be  invertible.

The $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors will form a basis $\mathcal{B}$. The matrix $P$ is thus the change-of-basis matrix from the standard basis to $\mathcal{B}$. The change-of-basis matrix always has an inverse ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25779/859382)).

Therefore $P$ is invertible $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is diagonalizable $\Leftrightarrow$ algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ has $n$ *distinct* eigenvalues ($k = n$) $\Leftrightarrow$ $P$ is square.